# First Order Linear Differential Equations having two solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have a linear first order ordinary differential equation
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan (x) y = 2 \cos^2 x \sin x - \sec x$$ with an initial condition as $y(\frac{\pi}{4})=3 \sqrt2$

My integrating factor $\mu(x)=\sec x$

After multiplication with the integration factor what I get is:

$$(secx\ y)'=sin2x-sec^2x$$ or $$(secx\ y)'=2 sinx cosx-sec^2x$$

If I use the first equation I get:

$$y(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}cos2x-tanx+c}{secx}$$

and using the second equation I get:

$$y(x)=\frac{sin^2x-tanx+c}{secx}$$

($\int 2\ sinx\ cosx\ dx = 2 \frac{sin^2x}{2}=sin^2x$)

with the first equation I get $c=7$ and second equation I get $c=\frac{13}{2}$.

It is a very simple differential equation but when I solve it I get two different answers.
Is this ok?

Comment: What does mean $\tan xy$ ?

Comment: ytanx....i need to up my mathjax skills...i know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primitive of $\sin(2x)$ is $-\frac12\cos(2x)$. Then the difference in the integration constants $c$ is just the constant term in the double-angle formula $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$.

Comment: So all these solutions belong to the same family of solutions eventually?

Comment: Yes, the difference is just a constant (in the final solution formula, a homogeneous solution) that gets absorbed in the general integration constant.

Comment: thanks a lot @Lutz Lehmann....